# A really simple distinct query uses temporary tables

Tags: mysql, wordpress

For some reason this really simple WordPress query uses temporary table. I've even tried forcing it use the index but to no avail.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT(meta_key) FROM wp_postmeta

+------+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-----------------+
| id   | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra           |
+------+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-----------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | wp_postmeta | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1756487 | Using temporary |
+------+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-----------------+


SHOW INDEX FROM wp_postmeta

+-------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| wp_postmeta |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | meta_id     | A         |     1756487 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_postmeta |          1 | post_id  |            1 | post_id     | A         |      159680 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| wp_postmeta |          1 | meta_key |            1 | meta_key    | A         |        1578 |      191 | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: This seems just a statement of fact - is there a question you are asking?

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: @Strawberry what made you say that?

Comment: My prefrontal cortex, I think.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try using `GROUP BY` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT`?

```
SELECT meta_key
FROM wp_postmeta
GROUP BY meta_key
```

Comment: Still the same.